# How to open network folder with XUL

Tags: javascript, xul, toolbar

How can I open network folder for XUL? for my Firefox toolbar, it can access drives like `C:`, not network paths like `//Development`...with the code: `file.initWithPath("\\DEVELOPMENT2");`

Full code:

```
var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"]
         .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);

file.initWithPath("\\\DEVELOPMENT2"); //---> this is not working

//file.initWithPath("Y:");  ---> this is working

file.reveal();

var process = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/process/util;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIProcess);
    process.init(file);

var args = [];
process.run(false, args, args.length);

//end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two issues:

- Missing bachslash - you need two backslashes, each of them escaped, this makes four backslashes in total. Meaning `"\\\\DEVELOPMENT2"` rather than `"\\\DEVELOPMENT2"`.
- Firefox cannot open the listing for a server - it is a virtual location, not an actual folder. It can open any of the shared folders on the server however:

```js
var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"]
         .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);

file.initWithPath("\\\\DEVELOPMENT2\\folder");
file.reveal();
```